# Creating a password protected Cydia repository?

Tags: authentication, iphone

The title pretty much sums it all.

I'm evaluating using Cydia to distribute iPod/iPad/iPhone apps to a restricted set of users.
I got a hang on how to setup a repository, but cannot figure whether it is possible to lock it or not.
Even a simple authentication scheme (static login/password) would be good enough.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: For those who aren't aware, Cydia uses apt for package distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also trying to do this, but nobody else knew. I think I found the solution, I just don't have it working yet. If you want to try yourself, you will need to know PHP and mod_rewrite. Cydia sends the UDID along with a few more special headers in $_SERVER:

```
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Telesphoreo APT-HTTP/1.0.592
[HTTP_X_FIRMWARE] => 4.0.1
[HTTP_X_MACHINE] => iPhone3,1
[HTTP_X_UNIQUE_ID] => xxxxxxxx
```

You could use mod rewrite and send Release to Release.php, same with Packages and Packages.gz. Then check if $_SERVER['HTTP_X_UNIQUE_ID'] is in a list of approved device ids before including the requested information. I'm not sure how well this will work, but I am going to try it. I am having troubles with Cydia finding changes in repos, but I'm sure this could be fixed by sending a few modified date headers.

Comment: That's an interesting way to deal with the issue you have there, though not exactly what I'm after since it would involve having to track all devices ids, generating quite a process overhead (user side). I might consider it though if nothing better shows up.